# JNDI DataSource: migrating from Tomcat to jBoss/Wildfly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jpa, jboss

I have a web application that uses Tomcat 7, Spring MVC 4.0, and JPA (Hibernate implementation). I am migrating this application to jBoss/Wildfly application server.

Currently, the DataSource is injected in the application with JNDI in a Spring configuration file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MY_DB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

The data source itself is defined in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` in the following way:

```
<Context> 
    <Resource name="jdbc/MY_DB" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_DB?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" 
        username="user1" 
        password="" 
        validationQuery="select 1" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120" 
        maxWait="60" 
        maxActive="20" 
        maxIdle="10" /> 
</Context>
```

How can I define this JNDI DataSource in JBoss/Wildfly?

Comment: Take a look in https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 and https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must make the JDBC driver available to the application server; then you can configure the data source itself.

See more details in [Data Source Configuration in AS 7](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7) and [DataSource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration)

Comment: This comment is just for my own records: a JDBC driver and a data source can also be defined throw the Admin Console (a web interface). At first, I registered the driver at the `Deployments` tab, but it kept disappearing after every few restarts of WildFly (I start it from Eclipse). So I had to define the JDBC driver as a module.

Comment: After you create a module in the `modules/` directory, the module should be referenced in the `<datasources><drivers>` section of the config file as described [here](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/index.html). Only after that you will be able to create a new data source in the Admin Console.

Comment: @Alex The recommended way to install a JDBC driver into WildFly 8 is to deploy it as a regular JAR deployment. Any JDBC 4-compliant driver will automatically be recognized and installed into the system by name and version.  See more https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration